# How to calculate the angle of a point when you know the distance between 4 points?

Tags: geometry

If you have 3 points, and know the distance between these points, and the distance between each point and one other point, how do you calculate the angle of each point?

Say that you have 3 points (A, B and C). You measure the distance of a source (point D) from each point. Each point has a 1m space in between each. The distance of line AD is 9m, line BD is 10m, and CD is 8m. How do you calculate the angle between each point and the source?

EDIT: Sorry, I'm not great at explaining math. Basically, point A, B, and C are each in a line. Point D is somewhere in space. together, point A, B, C, and D create a triangle. All lines must converge somewhere. You know the distance between each point and D. The angle I'm primarily looking for is the angle ABD, or DBC.

It'd kinda be like this (Not representative of the values I presented):

. D

A B C

Comment: Any point 'X' at distance 'd' from point 'A' lives in a circumference centered at 'A'  with radius 'd' .Perhaps if you draw a sketch with all circumferences you get new ideas.

Comment: An angle is between two lines.  What other line makes the angle with AD, for example?

Comment: When you say $A,B,C$ are each in a line, do you mean they are aligned with AB=1m, BC=1m and AC=2m ? Or they form an equilateral triangle with sidelength 1m ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generate a figure based on your description:

[image: impossible triangles]

All the triangles on the figure are "impossible" triangles. For instance, on $[BCD]$ you have a triangle with sizes $1$, $8$ and $10$. Since $1+8=9<10$ there's no such triangle.

However, if you increase the lengths between $A$, $B$ and $C$ (and make the triangles "possible") you can easily find $\alpha$ with the Law of Cosines.